# Override an inline style added by jQuery in a var function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This jQuery function assigns an inline style of `opacity:0.25` to each element with a class of `grid-item`. How do I override that and add CSS of `opacity:1` to the HTML element `title` that is within `grid-item`?

This is the function that assigns an inline style of opacity .25 to the selected items that have a class of `grid-item`. It's part of a larger Isotope function that filters selected items.

```
// change opacity for selected/unselected items
  var selectedClass = '.' + selectedCategory;
  $items.filter(selectedClass).css({
    opacity: 1
  });
  $items.not(selectedClass).css({
    opacity: 0.25
  });
```

This is the HTML that results:

```
<div class="grid-item" style="opacity: 0.25;">
<div class="title">
</div>
</div>
```

How do I add CSS of `opacity:1` to a `title` element? Either inline or in the style sheet?

Conceptually, this is what I need to do:

```
$items.not(selectedClass) $('.title').css('opacity',''1');
```

My question is how to add that to the function above? Or is there a better way?

Simply trying `!important` in the style sheet

```
.grid-item .title {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

doesn't work.

**Edit:**

It appears that you can't change the opacity of a child element [Disable opacity on child element when parent element has opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457057/disable-opacity-on-child-element-when-parent-element-has-opacity) unless you use `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)` on the parent. But trying `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)` in the function instead of `opacity: 1` breaks it. How do I do this?:

```
// change opacity for selected/unselected items
      var selectedClass = '.' + selectedCategory;
      $items.filter(selectedClass).css({
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)  //breaks
      });
      $items.not(selectedClass).css({
        opacity: 0.25
      });
```

Comment: You can use `.find()`... `$items.not(selectedClass).find('.title').css(...` but if the parent element is opacity `.25`, I don't think you can set a child to be more opaque than its parent.

Comment: I looked around and you're right about opacity; looks like I can use `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)` re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457057/disable-opacity-on-child-element-when-parent-element-has-opacity  But changing the `opacity: 0.25` to the background CSS breaks the function becuase of the ( and )

Answer (score 0):

Inline css has higher priority than external stylesheets so you have to do it with `js` like so:

```
$('.title').css({
    opacity: 1
});
```

For background opacity, wrap it into quotation marks:

```
$items.filter(selectedClass).css({
    background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
});
```

Comment: It isn't a problem of priority, since the OP use `!important` in the style sheet and it's on a different element anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work; I just discovered that opacity can't easily be overridden unless I use background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457057/disable-opacity-on-child-element-when-parent-element-has-opacity

Comment: @BlueDogRanch completely missed that, you're correct.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

well...

You can not override "opacity" in a nested element by css definition, but you can give the other nested elements opacity by simply using the .find method.

```
$items.not(selectedClass).find('*').not('.title').css('opacity','0.25');
```

if there is just one dimension under the element you can use .children instead to increase time.

```
$items.not(selectedClass).children().not('.title').css('opacity','0.25');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's difficult to change the opacity of a child element when the parent opacity is less. See question edit.

Answer (score 0):

When your .title element is in a div with opacity: 0.25 and so opacity of itself is 0.25 the real opacity of this element is 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.0625.
And if you set the opacity of .title to 1.0 it has a real opacity 0.25.

This code is true:

```
.grid-item .title {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

And it overrides the inline jquery added styles but it is not what you want for the reason that i said.

and update your code:

```
 var selectedClass = '.' + selectedCategory;
  $items.filter(selectedClass).css({
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)  //breaks
  });
  $items.not(selectedClass).css({
    opacity: 0.25
  });
```

to this:

```
 var selectedClass = '.' + selectedCategory;
  $items.filter(selectedClass).css({
  background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'  //breaks
  });
  $items.not(selectedClass).css({
    opacity: '0.25'
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's difficult to change the opacity of a child element when the parent opacity is less. See question edit.

Comment: If you want .title opacity works true all of its parents must have opacity 1.