# Make specific underlying elements to behave/render like being above the overlay

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, dom-events

How can one keep just some child elements clearly visible, when the parent is opaque, without affecting the rendering performances of the page?

I am trying to make **specific elements under an overlay** to react and to be rendered **as if they were above the overlay**.

- is there any way in CSS to influence the rendering of **specific** underlaying elements when blending with the overlay? Or is the `mix-blend-mode` working just top-down direction? (e.g. I'd like to tell *just* `.visible` to blend with the overlay differently; while all the rest underneath should have the normal blending)
- is `filter` working just on the selected element? Doesn't it affects the rendering of underlaying elements, when the selected element has opacity?
  (e.g. Make the *overlay* make everything below as greyscale)

And, since I assume the answers of both questions above won't help me, the actual question is:

- Is it possible to visually compensate, on the `.visible` elements, the opacify effect

## Note:

I know that one solution could be to use a selector:

```
div.data :not(.visible) { opacify: .5; }
```

rather than using an *overlay*, but I have doubts how performances would be (especially on not powerful mobiles) trying to apply `opacify` to the *thousands* of `.data`-subelements that would be `:not(.visible)`. And also the *click*|*hover* on the opacified/disabled elements wouldn't be prevented (while I want just click on the area of the `.visible` to be caught).

### Any performant solution? Or what I am asking is impossible nowadays?

I tried to write an example snippet but I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

#### Javascript is also accepted

The priority is to have that visual/functional effect with decent performances on a generic mobile, when the number of `li` is above 100 and each of them contains 100 DOM elements.

```css
/* structure */
div.data { display: table; }
ul { display: table-row-group; }
li { display: table-row; }
li > div { display: table-cell; }
/* style */
li > div.content { color: red; }
.visible { color: green; border: 1px dashed black; padding: 0 5px; }
/* Overlay */
.data:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
}
/* reduce emphasis */
.data:after {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .5;
}
/* visual "disabled" effect */
.data:after {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div class="content">Foobar1</div>
    <div>
     <span class="content">other content</span>
     <span class="visible">
      Not opaque
      <input type="checkbox" checked />
     </span>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="content">Foobar2</div>
    <div>
     <span class="content">other content</span>
     <span class="visible">
      Not opaque
      <input type="checkbox" />
     </span>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "...but I have doubts how performances would be..." if they are just doubts, then test them? Perhaps you'll be surprised by the results

Comment: I didn't try that method before, just read about it, but actually that works only for the `.visible` element but doesn't work as intended with all the other semitransparent elements, because the `opacity` is halved more and more for each descendant of `.data`. My method was to add an `:after`-pseudo-element to each `table-cell` so to apply the effect there (on each single overlay); and that was killing performances when trying to add/remove those hundreds pseudo-elements on the fly (the overlay[s] need to be activated/deactivated with a click).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457057/disable-opacity-on-child-element-when-parent-element-has-opacity) is where I read of it, but that solution considers just one-level depth for the opaque/non-opaque sub-elements of `.data`.