# opacity for table but dont want to apply that opacity in the div present inside td tag of the table

Tags: html

I am using opacity for my table but i dont want to apply that opacity in the div as i mentioned,how to achieve this?

```
<table  class="popup" style="background-color:#898989;
width:99%;  opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80); >
    <tr>
      <td>
         <div>i dont want to apply transparency here</div>
      <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

by default its applying transparency throughout a table,which i dont want.

**Note**:i cant use RGBa as it is not compatible with IE7,8

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

sorry previous solution was not correct.

you might want to check out these related questions:

[I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css)

[Resetting the opacity of a child element - Maple Browser (Samsung TV App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508877/resetting-the-opacity-of-a-child-elements-maple-browser-samsung-tv-app)

this link explains how to use a `better fallback` for `ie6 and 7` , when using `rgba`

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="opacity: 1;">i dont want to apply transparency here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rgba value for your background

```
<table  class="popup" style="background-color: rgba(137,137,137,0.8);
width:99%;  >
    <tr>
      <td>
         <div>i dont want to apply transparency here</div>
      <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i cant use RGBa as it is not compatible with IE7,8

Comment: you can set background image of 1x1 pixel with good color for fallback

Comment: i can but that is not what i want

Comment: what about using css3pie ?  http://css3pie.com/

Comment: ya i did a search on that but i wanted a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply opacity to parent element use RGB color if you want transparent color or use an image.

Comment: i cant use RGBa as it is not compatible with IE7,8

Comment: you can use in ie via css filters check these links they might be helpful :)

http://goo.gl/Zgy83H    &    


http://goo.gl/Ri0bYp