# Allow opacity on container but not child elements

Tags: css

Basically, I have a `div` with background set to an image and `opacity` of `0.5`.  Inside the `div`, I am trying to place the same `img` as a circle.  However, it gets the 0.5 `opacity` too.

What is a good way to make sure this doesn't happen?

```
<div class="bg-img" ng-style="{'background':'url({{vm.large}}) center / cover'}">
    <img ng-src="{{vm.large}}">
</div>

.bg-img {
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.bg-img img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @user1354934 after reading your question for a few more times, is the effect that you want to achieve an rectangular image that is opaque in the center circle but faded in other area? If that's the case, `rgba()` might not be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**
The `rgba` syntax does not work for background image. Answer by [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34125491/605840) is better in this case.

**Update**

A better explanation is available at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509036/605840).

**Original**

`opacity` is applied to the full sub-tree. If you don't want it to be applied to child element, you can use `rgba` syntax [as suggested by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

Example: `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) url(<your_url>);`

Answer (score 4):

With [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity), the effect applies to the entire element, including child elements and content.

*From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):*

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

The exception to this rule is `background-color` set with `rgba()`.

The `rgba()` rule allows for the `opacity` to be set via the alpha channel.

So you could set the parent to `div { background-color: rgba (0, 255, 255, 0.5); }`, and that would set the `opacity` to `0.5` on the `background-color` alone. Child elements would be unaffected.

Learn more here: [A brief introduction to Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

If using an image is a must, see these posts:

- [Can I set an opacity only to the background image of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7241341/3597276)
- [CSS: set background image with opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4183948/3597276)