# Tailwind css opacity

Tags: css, opacity, tailwind-css

In my app I've a model. I'm using opacity on a model. 
The problem that I have now is that the body of the model
should not have opacity how could I fix this? Only outside the model 
should have opacity!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-red min-h-screen">
    <div class="fixed w-full h-full bg-blue opacity-50 flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
    <div class="bg-black p-16">
      <p class="text-white">Model body</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

I know it's been almost three years, and I'm not sure if this is what you want in your situation. But using `bg-opacity-{n}` instead of `opacity-{n}` did the trick for me.

I wanted to display an overlay element with kind of blackish background, but the overlay element itself should have 100% opacity.

Example code:

```html
<div className="p-20 border-4 border-black fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 right-0 w-full h-screen bg-black bg-opacity-75">
    <div className="bg-white bg-opacity-100">
        Sample Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Posting this in case anyone else needs a solution like this.

**TL;DR** - use `bg-opacity-75` in parent `div`, and `bg-opacity-100` in child `div`. Using `opacity-75` and `opacity-100` doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout 'Changing the opacity' for background color with Tailwind:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity

For example in this example 'bg-sky-500' will have an opacity of 50:

```
<button class="bg-sky-500/50 ..."></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `.opacity-100` to the nested div.

Check the Official Tailwind Documentation about [Opacity](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/opacity/) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, but then all opacity is gone. Only the opacity on the model body should go away.

Comment: Did you add the class to the p element?

Comment: I have the same issue. Adding opacity-100 to the nested div does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply opacity to a container, all its content and children will inherit
the opacity.
You can see this question on Stackoverflow:
[Allow opacity on container but not child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125438/allow-opacity-on-container-but-not-child-elements)

The solution is to apply opacity value to `background-color`. In tailwind you
can do it with `bg-blue-{opacity}` like `bg-blue-100`

Answer (score 0):

You need to play around with **relative/absolute**, **opacity** and **z-index**

Here's a [jsfiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/361snoqd/2/).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
     return {
        modalOpen: false
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="relative">
  <div class="h-screen w-full p-4">
    <span class="rounded p-2 bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer" @click="modalOpen = true;">
      Open Modal
    </span>
  </div>

  <div v-if="modalOpen" class="absolute bg-black opacity-25 inset-0 z-10" @click="modalOpen = false;"></div>

  <div class="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center" v-if="modalOpen">
    <div class="bg-white p-8 z-20">
      Modal
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `bg-opacity-40` to the outer div solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

As of **tailwind 3.3** the most the upvoted answer ie by @m01010011
in 2021 did not work for me, but @florestan-korp's 2022 answer is working for me.

ie  `bg-primary-blue/50` is working but `bg-opacity-50` is not working.
I dont have any nesting, just a plain old button:

```
<button className='g-primary-blue/50' disabled={props.isButtonDisabled}> Buttonname </button>
```

For nested div that answer may still be fine.