# Changing the opacity of the body except one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make the document opacity `0.5` except for one div. Can any one help me with this? I have tried to do the following:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("body").css({ opacity: '0.5' });
    $("#DIV").css({ opacity: '1' });
});
```

Comment: wait. If you set css to body, then all elements will have an effect of it.

Comment: `$("body").find("*:not(#DIV)").css({opacity:'0.5'});` You can use this.

Comment: The `opacity` property applies to the element as a whole, meaning all content will share equal transparency. If you set an opacity to `body`, the `div` will have it as well. Consider an rgba alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13508877/3597276